If $\{v_n\}\subset L^2(0,T;L^p(\Omega))$ be bounded then does it admit a bounded subsequence in $L^p(\Omega)$ a.e on $(0,T)$?
Let $n\geq3$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be bounded, $(2^*)'\leq p< 2^*$, $\{v_n\}\subset L^2(0,T;L^p(\Omega))$ be bounded :
$$\exists C>0: \ \|v_n\|_{L^2(L^p)}^2=\int\limits_0^T \big\|v_n(t)\big\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^2dt\leq C^2,\ \forall n.  $$
I wonder if $\{v_n\}$ admits a subsequence $\{v_{n_k}\}$ such that $\big\{v_{n_k}(t)\big\}$ be bounded in $L^p(\Omega)$ for $t\in (0,T)$ almost everywhere ?
My solution:
From the Banach–Alaoglu theorem, the closed ball $B=\big\{v:\ \|v\|_{L^2(L^p)}\leq C \big\}$ is weakly compact in $L^2(0,T;L^p(\Omega))$. Thus, there a weakly convergent subsequence $\{v_{n_k}\}$ with the limit $v\in B $. However, I don't know if this is enough to conclude the existence of a a.e bounded on $(0,T)$ subsequence. May anyone give me some idea ? Thanks.

what is $2^*$??

$2^*=\displaystyle\frac{2n}{n-2}$, the Sobolev conjugate of $2$.
